# Jemmy strucked at clickMouse() when notification dialog with progressbar are displayed

Tags: java, automated-tests, jemmy

During autotest execution ([jemmy](/questions/tagged/jemmy) lib is used to interact with Java GUI elements) address data is entered and button 'Search for address' is pressed. At some addresses notification dialog with progressbar are displayed.

Tried to set differenet timeouts but it does not help to identify (timeout expeired) that test is strucked at `searchByAddressButton.clickMouse();`

This question is a copy of ["Jemmy strucked at clickMouse() when notification dialog with progressbar are displayed"](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18734/jemmy-strucked-at-clickmouse-when-notification-dialog-with-progressbar-are-dis) at SQA.stackexchange.com. Please check it for full information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `NoBlock` operation (`.pushNoBlock();`, `.pushMenuNoBlock("File|Open");`) with manually set timer `ComponentOperator.WaitComponentTimeout` and checking for any new component that should appear in GUI:

```
JemmyProperties.setCurrentTimeout("ComponentOperator.WaitComponentTimeout", 5000); // 5 seconds
...
searchByAddressButton.pushNoBlock();
new JTabbedPaneOperator(flsFrame, 0);   // check that new object has appeared (in 5 seconds)
```